# Trace32 - PBI=MCIServer Illegal commad error

Tags: trace32, lauterbach

I am creating a ubicom-32 core under MCI-Server configuration in T32 tree(t32 start).

When i am starting the Core, I get

```
PBI=MCIServer (Illegal command)
Config=C:\Temp\T321000023.t32
T32SYS = C:\T32\ (config file)
```

I have the below settings in my T321000023.t32 file which is autogenerated.

```
;Connection to Host
PBI=MCISERVER
NODE=localhost
INSTANCE=1
CORE=4
```

How to fix this? Any other config is required for MCIServer set up? 
I am not getting the error when i start ubicom32 core via simulator/JTAG dongle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lauterbach supports MCI-Server configuration only for a limited number of target processor architectures and currently Ubicom32 is not in the list of supported architectures.

Support for MCI-Server configuration requires not only effort to implement this feature for an architecture, but it also requires customers that have interest in this feature and are willing to purchase it. Please contact Lauterbach support support@lauterbach.com to discuss feasibility and conditions.